# Can "where" be omitted in the following?

Tags: adverbs, ellipsis

Can "where" be omitted in situations like these?

> The waiter carried the order to the table (where) the group was
> sitting.
>
> "We're going to the place (where) you're going to be trained."

Comment: No, it can't. The table isn't the object of the verb _sit_, or the place that of _be trained_.

Comment: @KateBunting - I beg to differ. The first doesn't work, but the second does, colloquially.

Comment: You can get better answers if you explain a bit about why you think it might be. Note, you can omit it if you add a preposition at the end: "The waiter carried the order to the table the group was sitting **at**." (And if someone tells you you can't end a sentence with a preposition, [they're wrong](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of, but sometimes you need to tweak it, otherwise it just sounds like there's a word missing…

> The waiter carried the order to the table (where) the group was sitting.

could be re-cast as

> The waiter carried the order to the table the group was sitting **at**.

On the other hand,

> We're going to the place you're going to be trained.

really doesn't want the "at" as a replacement.

I'm still trying to reason *why* there's this difference… perhaps some else can provide that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe because "place" and "where" are almost the same idea?

Comment: I honestly don't know. This is one of those judgement calls you make every day as a native speaker & often you're not exactly sure *why,* you just *know* which fits best. Rules you learned by 'absorption' from other natives as you grew up.

Answer (score 0):

no,sometimes you can drop where in situation where the word before "where" is unspecific place,such as somewhere,everywhere.
this is what I get from Practical English Usage

> The same thing happens with where after somewhere, anywhere, everywhere, nowhere and place (but not after other words).
> Have you got somewhere (that) I can lie down for an hour?
> We need a place (that) we can stay for a few days. (but not We need a house we can stay for a few days.)

Comment: OK, _where_ is preceded by _place_ in the second sentence, but not in the first.

Comment: If you're quoting something, please provide the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think @CN.hitori has got the right answer.

Here is a more extensive quote from Practical English Usage (by Michael Swan, Oxford University Press):

> After common nouns referring to time, *when* is often replaced by *that* or dropped in an informal style.
> *Come and see us **anytime (that)** you're in town.*
> ...
>
> The same thing happens with *where* after *somewhere, anywhere, everywhere, nowhere,* and *place* (but not after other words).
> *Have you got **somewhere (that)** I can lie down for an hour.*
> *We need a **place (that)** we can stay for a few days.*
> BUT NOT: *<strike>We need a **house** we can stay for a few days.</strike>*